# JOOQ Mysql integration issue

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have setup JOOQ for MySQL. Compilation for various tables is done and now I am trying to run the following query:

`dsl.selectFrom(WALLPAPER).where(WALLPAPER.PARENT_ID.eq(id)).orderBy(WALLPAPER.VIEW_ORDER).fetchInto(WallpaperItem.class);`

But I keep getting this error

`"org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select "library"."wallpaper"."id", "library"."wallpaper"."category_name", "library"."wallpaper"."icon", "library"."wallpaper"."view_order", "library"."wallpaper"."parent_id" from "library"."wallpaper" where "library"."wallpaper"."parent_id" = cast(? as int) order by "library"."wallpaper"."view_order" asc]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '."wallpaper"."id", "library"."wallpaper"."category_name", "library"."wallpaper' at line 1`

What could the issue be?

Comment: My MySQL does not like the syntax with "schemaName"."Table"."Column". The quotation marks are the problem. I use backtick ` instead. No idea how to bring that to JOOQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generated SQL uses double quotes (`"name"`) for your schema / table / column names. This is what's causing the syntax error on MySQL, which expects names to be quoted using backticks (`` `name` ``).

The reason why double quotes are generated is because you configured your `dsl` reference with the wrong `SQLDialect`, i.e. with something other than `SQLDialect.MYSQL`. For example:

```
DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
```